# Python class constructor raises syntax error on keyword "def"

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am developing a simple bioinformatics package in Python. I have defined a class for working with FASTA files, but the interpreter raises a syntax error on a "def" keyword, line 8, ostensibly for the constructor.

There is no "def" keyword on line 8, and I cannot detect a syntax error in the code I've written--can I get some other eyes on this? Or perhaps a recommendation as to how to fix the interpreter?

```
class FastaToolbox:
def __init__(self, inputPath, seqType):
    self.input = inputPath
    self.seqType = seqType
    self.validNucleic = ['a','g','c','t','u','r','y','k','m','s','w','b','d','h','v','n','-']
    self.validAmino = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S'
                        'T','U','V','W','Y','Z','X','*','-']
    self.warnings = []
    for char in self.validNucleic:
        if char != '-':
            self.validNucleic.append(upper(char))
    for char in self.validNucleic:
        if char != '-' and char != '*':
            self.validAmino.append(lower(char))
def validateFasta(self):
    if self.seqType == 'nucleic':
        for char in range (0, len(self.seq) - 1):
            if seq[char] not in validNucleic:
                print("ERR! Seq %s has invalid read at pos %i", self.seqHeader, char)
                self.warnings.append(self.seq)
    else:
        for char in range (0, len(self.seq) - 1):
            if seq[char] not in validAmino:
                print("ERR! Seq %s has invalid read at pos %i", self.seqHeader, char)
                self.warnings.append(self.seq)
```

Comment: There is no indentation, you need to add some space before def

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, all def's should be inside the class

Comment: You need to indent your code appropriately.

Comment: Once you fix that you have a multitude of NameErrors to look forward to, if you don't understand indentation, you should probably avoid classes, you have  `self.seq`, `seq`,  `validAmino` and a whole lot more undefined

Comment: The indentation is correct in Atom but when I posted the code here it didn't translate correctly. I will try using a character other than 'tab' within my text editor; perhaps that will resolve the issue. Also, 'vaildAmino' gets defined as an instance variable within the constructor, seems like that shouldn't be an issue.

I'll refactor this and figure it out

Comment: Don't mix tabs and spaces, preferably just use spaces

Comment: Nevermind. Classic glitch--I have been attempting to run the wrong file for ~10 minutes. I will flag this question.